# Spamprotection / Recaptcha on SS4

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I’m unable to get [silverstripe-recaptcha](https://github.com/chillu/silverstripe-recaptcha) and [silverstripe-spamprotection](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-spamprotection) working on SS4 with [silverstripe-userforms](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-userforms).

In my app/_config/spamprotection.yml:

```
SilverStripe\SpamProtection\Extension\FormSpamProtectionExtension:
  default_spam_protector: SilverStripe\Recaptcha\RecaptchaProtector
```

In my app/_config/recaptcha.yml:
Note: have tried with and without quotes around the api keys.

```
SilverStripe\Recaptcha\RecaptchaField:
  public_api_key: xxx
  private_api_key: xxx
```

I have:

- Done a dev/build and ?flush
- Added the anti-spam field in my userform

No errors / warnings in the console.

Has anybody got this working?
Can you see what I’m missing?

Comment: I've tested this locally and it works for me. SilverStripe 4, recaptcha module, spam protection module, userforms module. spamprotection.yml and recaptcha.yml as described above. Simple user form with a couple of fields and a spam protection field. It works for me.

Comment: Perhaps `SilverStripe\SpamProtection\Extension\FormSpamProtectionExtension` is being overwritten in another config somewhere else. Check all your `app/_config/` yml files to see if `FormSpamProtectionExtension` is being redefined somewhere else. Or perhaps the field in the user form page has not been published. Try publishing the page again and checking that the spam field still appears in the field list in the back end.

Comment: It was being overridden by another module. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was another module was setting `SilverStripe\SpamProtection\Extension\FormSpamProtectionExtension`, overriding the setting in my `app/_config/spamprotection.yml` file.

One solution is to set our `spamprotection.yml` to load after the other module's yml file. We can do this by adding the following to the top of our yml file:

```
---
Name: app-spamprotection
After: '#galadriel'
---
SilverStripe\SpamProtection\Extension\FormSpamProtectionExtension:
  default_spam_protector: SilverStripe\Recaptcha\RecaptchaProtector
```

In the above example `galadriel` is the `Name` set in the other module's yml file.